# Get id, From href

Tags: jquery

I successfully get string first_slide, second_slide etc, I want to get ID form that string: 
like on click: the development
i want to get its id: 1,

```
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#first_slide" id="1">the development</a></li>
                <li><a href="#second_slide" id="2">the design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#third_slide" id="3">the locate</a></li>
                <li><a href="#fourth_slide" id="4">the layout</a></li>
                <li><a href="#fifth_slide" id="5">the team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sixth_slide" id="6">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `this.id` inside `.click()` handler of anchors:

```
$('ul li a').click(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MWsa5/)**

If you use `.click()` handler on `<li>` elements then you can use `.find()` along with `.attr()` or `.prop()`:

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).find('a').prop('id')); 
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MWsa5/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
$('a').click(function(){
    console.log(this.id)
})
```